# Is there a base $b\geq11$ that we obtain a perfect power after we concatenate the first $n$ positive integers of that base?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, perfect-powers

Is there a base $b\geq11$ that we obtain a perfect power after we concatenate the first $n$ positive integers of that base?

In base ten, the concatenation of first $n$ positive integers does not give any other perfect power other than $1$.

But what about on other bases?

Note that I excluding cases like $1, 12, 123$, as those are somewhat trival.

I did already check all bases greater than ten, but $\leq36$ to check if there is a base $b$ such that $1234_{b}, 12345_{b}$ and $123456_{b}$ are perfect powers, but there is none.

I mean when I say concatenation on other bases, it is like this, example in base twenty-two:

$1_{22},12_{22},123_{22},\cdots,123456789abcdefghjkl10_{22}$.

In general, $1,12,123,\cdots,123\cdots(b-1)10$.

I know these things:

$6$ is never the last digit of a perfect power on bases that are divisible by four or nine.

$2$ is never a perfect power on bases that is divisible by four.

By using Phyton, I tried to check all bases from eleven to thirty-six to check if are there any perfect powers that is obtained by concatenating the first $n$ positive integers of that base, but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: The $1234$ case should yield to the people who know about elliptic curves because it asks if $b^3+2b^2+3b+4=c^2$has a solution in the integers.

Comment: @RossMillikan the **1234** case doesn't ask only about the integer solutions of $b^3+2b^2+3b+4=c^2$ but about the integer solutions of $b^3+2b^2+3b+4=c^k$. OP asked about perfect power. Not only perfect squares.